# Iphone application crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

my application is crashes because of this line of code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
```

Comment: Crash log? If you don't mind.

Comment: It's neither a question nor a bug.

Comment: thanks .i have changed code and now it is working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code in my applications, but i am not getting any crash in my all applications.

Can you put full method code?

And try clean your project , delete it from simulator and run it.

Comment: thanks. i changed that code and now every thing is working ok.